# Как сделать так, чтобы при изменении в TextBox сразу отрисовывался объект?

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеем: XAML

```
<TextBox  Height="23" Name="TBLength" Width="60" Text="{Binding Path=L, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextChanged="Beam1_isChanged" />
```

К `TextBox` привязано свойство:

```
public double L 
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(LProperty); }
    set 
    {  SetValue(LProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty LProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("L", typeof(double), typeof(Beam),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());
```

И подписано событие `TextChanged="Beam1_isChanged"`
метод `Beam1_isChanged` должен рисовать, но при изменении значения в текстбоксе метод запускается со старыми параметрами, т.е. свойство не обновилось. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: покажите код метода `Beam1_isChanged`